# MySQL: строка добавляется не в конец

Tags: mysql

Я хочу удалить запись, а после добавить другую, но новая строка добавляется не в конец, а на место удаленной.
  Вот код который я использовал (auto increment отсутствует):

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `group table`.`id` = '2'

INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `column2`, `column3`) VALUES ('4', '4', '4');
```

В итоге после первого индекса идет четвертый. Как добавить новую строку в конец таблицы?

Comment: А вам зачем? Порядок в таблице совершенно не нужен. Если же он нужен - в SELECT используйте ORDER BY

Comment: В таблице порядка НЕТ. Таблица - это несортированная куча.

Comment: Зачем использовать удаление? Добавьте статус строчки и меняйте с 1 на 0 и обратно при необходимости. А новые данные будут в конце таблицы. Но как и сказали уже выше - для select не важно в каком порядке данные